# How to install the third-party python (2.7) modules (e.g. Pycrypto) on ARM?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arm, cross-compiling, pycrypto

I have compiled and installed Python-2.7.9 on my ARM-based device. 
When I try to install the [Pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto), there comes the problems as follows.

1. First, I downloaded the source code, did `python setup.py install`, but it went wrong by telling the the Pycrypto needs C compiler on ARM. Apparently my ARM does not have the C compiler. So this method of installation didn't work.
2. Then, I tried the `pip` and `easy_install` way. It still failed by telling `No matching distribution found for pycrypto` while I successfully installed on x86 platform (my Ubuntu) using the same pip command.

So, what I want to ask is that how to install the third-party python module which includes the C code, like Pycrypto, on ARM platform.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried installing a C compiler?

Comment: I thought about it, but I prefer not to. After all, installing C compiler and running it are some kind of burden to the ARM device.

Comment: Huh? The C compiler translates code to machine instructions _once_, when you build the package. The Python interpreter imposes the same "burden" on the device _all the time it is executing Python code_. That's a rather baffling viewpoint you have there...

Comment: You are right and I'll try it later.